# Box API v2 How to add a collaboration for a single user to a folder using email address?

Tags: box-api

I can do that using Box API v1, but v2 require user_id which I don't know how to get to send invitation.

Comment: v1 api: http://www.box.net/api/1.0/rest?action=invite_collaborators&api_key=rjcm1at5zbte17vxjblvqca2fsm9rl&auth_token=6elnk7x1fpecnv32tj5iya7ypzb&target=folder&target_id=7050508&user_ids[]=&emails[]=emailaddress%40gmail.com&item_role_name=editor&resend_invite=0&no_email=0&params[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to create collaborations based solely on an email address in the V2 API *yet*, although we plan to add support for this in the future.